# create a search field on BlackBerry-KeywordFilterField

Tags: search, blackberry, field

I want to create a search field, and I've found KeyworldFilterDemo on samples of Blackberry. But consists of a single text input field(top) and a list of selectable String elements. Is there any way to create that the list be a graphical components that contains a lot of information such us name email....
if any one types a caracter it displays all names started with it.

Comment: You may need to use changetext event in text field & according to textfield input, you can search in From some kind of predefind values storage like vector. Or Search for autocomplete field In Blackberry.

Comment: You can vote up my comment  , if you find some help.. :-)

Comment: I don't know how. Where sould I click plz? :)

Comment: Its fine.. I am glad.. i can help You !!